# Reprojecting a raster DEM from meters to feet using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, 3d-analyst, coordinate-system

Is there a tool in QGIS that does the same as reprojecting a raster DEM from meters to feet as in ArcGIS's 3D Analyst > Raster Math > Times ?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not actually 'reprojecting' the data (the coordinate system, that is), you're simply multiplying it by a constant (as in the 'times' tool in ArcGIS) to change the pixel values from one number to another, so you can use the [QGIS Raster Calculator](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html) to do this.

Comment: That works beautifully. Yet another free QGIS solution
!

Comment: @sirgeo fantastic!!!